# Hide one result from list in the db with field specified in nodejs sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using node js and sequelize for backend. I have a database which have some lists in the table with id starts from 1 - 100. What i want is i want to hide one row when showing the results to the front end side. For eg: i want to hide the row with id = 1 , so that it shows only the list  with id = 2-100 in the frontend. Is there any way to do this for hiding the list from the results

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to filter rows with id=1 by sequelize or afterwards when you have an array?

Comment: I want to list the array from Id = 2 to 100

Comment: Show a sequelize query and how you send a result from it to a client

Answer (score 0):

use the following query with sequelize:

```js
<your_model>.findAll({
    where: {
        id: {[Op.between]: [2, 100]}
    }
});
```

Dont forget to import or require Op from sequelize:

```js
const {Op} = require("sequelize");
// Or
import {Op} from 'sequelize';
```